# Trying to understand the behaviour of i.i.d.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

In a course called introduction to probability theorem we are covering now i.i.d. (independent and identically distributed random variables). I already know when two variables are independent: $X, Y$ are independent if $P(X \le a, Y \le b) = P(X \le a) \cdot P(Y \le b)$ for all possible choices of $a, b$.

The following definition comes from Wikipedia:

> In probability theory and statistics, a sequence or other collection
>   of random variables is **independent and identically distributed
>   (i.i.d.)** if each random variable has the same probability distribution
>   as the others and all are mutually independent.

What does "the same probability distribution" mean? That $P(X \le a) = P(y \le a)$ (assuming that we are interested in only two random variables, $X$ and $Y$)? What are (not necessary interesting) examples of i.i.d. variables, that aren't discrete?

This exercise has given rise to serious doubts regarding the understanding of random variables:

> **14.** Let $X, Y$ have the same probability distribution. Is it true that $\mathbb E[\frac{X}{X+Y}] = \mathbb E[\frac{Y}{X+Y}]$?

At first I thought that the answer if affirmative, but I've heard that there is a counterexample (which I can't find). If it's negative, what is wrong with my intuition behind such equalities?

Comment: Counterexample: assume that (X,Y) is uniform on the set {(0,1),(1,2),(2,0)} then X and Y are both uniform on {0,1,2} but E(X/(X+Y))=4/9 while E(Y/(X+Y))=5/9.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Very good questions.

If $X$ and $Y$ have the same probability distribution, than for every $z$, 
$$
   \Pr\left(X \leqslant z\right) = \Pr\left(Y \leqslant z\right)
$$
Then $X$ and $Y$ are said to be identically distributed. Note that this does not imply independence. A classic example would be [binormally distributed vector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Bivariate_case) of $(X,Y) \sim \mathcal{BN}\left(\rho\right)$:
$$
   f_{X,Y}\left(x,y\right) = \frac{1}{2\pi} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\rho^2}} \exp\left(-\frac{1}{2} \frac{x^2+y^2 + 2 \rho x y}{1-\rho^2}\right)
$$
It is straightforward to show that $f_X(z) = f_Y(z) =  \frac{1}{2\pi}\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2} z^2\right)$, yet $X$ and $Y$ are not independent, in fact
$$
   \mathbb{E}\left(X Y\right) = \rho \not= \mathbb{E}\left(X\right) \mathbb{E}\left(Y\right) = 0
$$
unless $\rho = 0$.

Regarding your second question, equality $\mathbb{E}\left(\frac{X}{X+Y}\right) = \mathbb{E}\left(\frac{Y}{X+Y}\right)$ requires [exchangeability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exchangeable_random_variables), i.e. $f_{X,Y}\left(x,y\right) = f_{X,Y}\left(y,x\right)$ for all $x$ and $y$, which does not follow from the identical distributions of $X$ and $Y$.

I used *Mathematica* to build a counter-example. Let $(X,Y)$ be a pair of discrete random variables from 1 to 3 with the following probability mass function:

$$
    p_{X,Y}\left(x,y\right) = \begin{cases}
 \frac{1}{17} & (x=2\land y=2)\lor (x=2\land y=1) \\
 \frac{14}{51} & (x=2\land y=3)\lor (x=3\land y=1) \\
 \frac{1}{3} & x=1\land y=2
\end{cases}
$$

Here is how I did it (code for this can be retrieved from [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/kZyyzcxe)).

First define a custom distribution over tuples of integers from 1 to 3:

```
p = EmpiricalDistribution[Array[pr, 3^2] -> Tuples[Range[3], 2]];
```

Now request that marginal CDFs are the same, and yet expectations are different:

```
In[58]:= {inst} = 
 FindInstance[
  sol = Reduce[
    ForAll[x, 
      CDF[MarginalDistribution[dist, 1], x] == 
       CDF[MarginalDistribution[dist, 2], x]] && 
     DistributionParameterAssumptions[dist] && 
     Array[0 <= pr[#] <= 1 &, 3^2, 1, And] && 
     Expectation[x/(x + y), {x, y} \[Distributed] dist] != 
      Expectation[y/(x + y), {x, y} \[Distributed] dist], Reals], 
  Array[pr, 3^2]]

Out[58]= {{pr[1] -> 0, pr[2] -> 1, pr[3] -> 0, pr[4] -> 3/17, 
  pr[5] -> 3/17, pr[6] -> 14/17, pr[7] -> 14/17, pr[8] -> 0, 
  pr[9] -> 0}}
```

Show the probability mass function:

```
In[62]:= PiecewiseExpand[PDF[counterExampleDist = dist /. inst, {x, y}]]

Out[62]= Piecewise[{{1/
    17, (x == 2 && y == 2) || (x == 2 && y == 1)}, {14/
    51, (x == 2 && y == 3) || (x == 3 && y == 1)}, {1/3, 
   x == 1 && y == 2}}, 0]
```

Now verify:

```
In[63]:= {CDF[MarginalDistribution[counterExampleDist, 1], x], 
 CDF[MarginalDistribution[counterExampleDist, 2], x]}

Out[63]= {1/3 Boole[1 <= x] + 20/51 Boole[2 <= x] + 
  14/51 Boole[3 <= x], 
 1/3 Boole[1 <= x] + 20/51 Boole[2 <= x] + 14/51 Boole[3 <= x]}

In[64]:= {Expectation[x/(
  x + y), {x, y} \[Distributed] counterExampleDist], 
 Expectation[y/(x + y), {x, y} \[Distributed] counterExampleDist]}

Out[64]= {379/765, 386/765}
```

[image]